# Python: Get last n Trues from Boolean array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a boolean array and a want to convert that to an array, where only the `last_n_trues` `True` values are still `True`. A simple example:

```
>>> boolean_array = [False, False, True, True, True, False, False]
>>> last_n_trues = 2
>>> desired_output = [False, False, False, True, True, False, False]
```

My approach:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> idxs_of_trues = np.where(boolean_array)[0] 
array([2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)

>>> idxs_of_trues_last_n = idxs_of_trues[-last_n_trues:] 
array([3, 4], dtype=int64)

>>> [x in idxs_of_trues_last_n for x in range(0, len(boolean_array))]
[False, False, False, True, True, False, False]
```

Is there a **faster** way to do so? Especially the list comprehension seems pretty complicated to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just be able to simply use `np.where`

```
In [116]: x
Out[116]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [117]: x[np.where(x)[0][:-2]] = False

In [118]: x
Out[118]: array([False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

This just replaces all `True` that aren't the last 2 with `False`

This will only work if `x` is a `np.array`, so verify that before you try this.

Comment: Seems like the fastest. Some magic is going on under the hoods : `np.where(x)[0][:-2]` is slow, but after indexing becomes super fast. Tested on 1.14.2.

Comment: It's actually 3x times faster than my version. And pretty straight forward! Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1 :** Here's one with [`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) -

```
def keep_lastNTrue_cumsum(a, n):
    c = np.count_nonzero(a) # or a.sum()
    a[c - a.cumsum() >= n] = 0
    return a
```

**Approach #2 :** Two more with [`argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) -

```
def keep_lastNTrue_argpartition1(a, n):
    c = np.count_nonzero(a) # or a.sum()
    a[np.sort(np.argpartition(a,-n)[-c:])[:-n]] = 0
    return a

def keep_lastNTrue_argpartition2(a, n):
    c = np.count_nonzero(a) # or a.sum()
    p = np.argpartition(a,-n)[-a.sum():]
    cn = c-n
    idx = np.argpartition(p,cn)
    a[p[idx[:cn]]] = 0
    return a
```

**Approach #3 :** Another with a bit more of mask usage -

```
def keep_lastNTrue_allmask(a, n):
    c = a.sum()
    set_mask = np.ones(c, dtype=bool)
    set_mask[:-n] = False
    a[a] = set_mask
    return a
```

Sample runs -

```
In [141]: boolean_array = np.array([False, False, True, True, True, False, False])

In [142]: keep_lastNTrue_cumsum(boolean_array, n=2)
Out[142]: array([False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False])

In [143]: boolean_array = np.array([False, False, True, True, True, False, False])

In [144]: keep_lastNTrue_argpartition1(boolean_array, n=2)
Out[144]: array([False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False])

In [145]: boolean_array = np.array([False, False, True, True, True, False, False])

In [146]: keep_lastNTrue_argpartition2(boolean_array, n=2)
Out[146]: array([False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False])
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way without libraries is going to be to clone the list and iterate through it in reverse:

```
def foo(bools, last_n_trues):
    result = bools[:]
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(bools) - 1, -1, -1):
        if count < last_n_trues:
            if result[i]:
                count += 1
        else:       
            result[i] = False
    return result
```